# express routing regex

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, express

I'm using the following regex
`/^\/(\d{5})$/` 
in a express route and I'm getting the following error

> SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: `/^\/^\/(?(?:([^\/]+?)){5})$\/?$/:` Invalid group.

This is the code I'm using:

> app.get("/^/(\d{5})$/", function(req, res, next){
>           console.log(req.params[0]);
>       )};

The regex works just fine when tested on the browser.

Thanks.

Comment: can you please post your expected output

Comment: I'm trying to match a  5 digits number, let's say the user send a request like /12345 I'm expecting to get 12345.

Comment: @Miguel please take a look on my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in my regex was the use of double quotes, this works:

`app.get(/^/(\d{5})$/, function(req, res, next){ console.log(req.params[0]); )};`

Answer (score 0):

I had time to look to your problem with more cation.

you needed to add an additional `\` in `\d{5}` use like:

> `app.route('/:id(\\d{5})').get(function(req, res, next){ console.log(req.params.id);});`

**Pay attention** that I setup the name for this parameter as `id`; you can change that.

http://expressjs.com/api.html

Comment: I get the same error using that regex  `SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^\/(?(?:([^\/]+?)){5})$\/?$/: Invalid group`